# Inno Setup default install folder change

Tags: installation, 64-bit, inno-setup, istool

Every time I compile my installer the default installation directory is C:\Program Files\Company\Product and I don't seem to be able to change it. Here's what I got under Setup:

```
[Setup]
AppName=MyProduct
AppVerName=MyProduct
AppPublisher=Company
DefaultDirName=C:\MyStuff\Company\MyProduct
DefaultGroupName=Company\MyProduct
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProduct.exe
UninstallDisplayName=MyProduct Uninstall
PrivilegesRequired=poweruser
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output
OutputBaseFilename=Setup
DisableDirPage=false
DisableProgramGroupPage=true
VersionInfoCompany=Company Inc
VersionInfoProductName=MyProduct
AllowUNCPath=false
```

Based on the documentations, DefaultDirName should dictate the default install folder. But it doesn't.

My case in particular is that, I want to set the default install folder on x64 machines to C:\Program Files, but the installer always picks Program Files (x86) no matter what I put in the DefaultDirName.

Comment: For an x86 app, `C:\Program Files (x86)\` and `C:\Program Files\` are the same folder.

Comment: If you have a 64-bit application then you should turn on 64-bit install mode, and then it will do what you seem to want.  If you have a 32-bit application then Inno is already doing the right thing, and trying to force it to install to the 64-bit Program Files folder would be very bad.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The last selected installation folder has the precedence before the [`DefaultDirName`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_defaultdirname.htm) directive value if the [`UsePreviousAppDir`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_usepreviousappdir.htm) directive is set to `yes`, which is by default. If you want to force the directory specified by the [`DefaultDirName`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_defaultdirname.htm) to be selected, turn off the [`UsePreviousAppDir`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_usepreviousappdir.htm) directive.

If you want to keep the functionality with the last directory, and just overcome this for your testing, simply uninstall the previous installation before you run the new built setup.

Comment: Note that you should normally **not** turn off `UsePreviousAppDir`, since doing that breaks user's expectations.  Uninstalling first while testing is the correct answer.

Comment: This `UsePreviousAppDir` default value was perplexing me for 2-3 hours until I found this...thanks..........I copied and pasted my script from my last program version, which I'm just now realizing includes the same `AppId`, presumably leading to this conflict. Using the uninstaller from my old version fixed the issue

Answer (score 6):

Just add "UsePreviousAppDir=no" in your iss file:

> [Setup]
>
> ...
>
> UsePreviousAppDir=no